# PHPMailer sends a second mail from the world4you FTP account

Tags: email, phpmailer

I'm having a really weird issue and after a long google search I couldn't find any similar problem to mine.

I'm having a registration form on my website and by submitting the form a confirmation mail is being sent to the user. Before putting the site online everything worked perfectly. Since I put my site online on the world4you server, I'm receiving two confirmation mails.
One is the original one where everything is perfectly formatted and the second one is apparently from the FTP server. 
The sender is: ftpxxxxxx@www94.world4you.com. ftpxxxxxx is my username for the ftp account.

Here is the phpmailer code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                        // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.world4you.com';                     // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                 // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Sender = 'office@barcamp-zukunftsdialog.at';
$mail->Username = 'office@barcamp-zukunftsdialog.at';   // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'xxxxxxxx';                               // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                              // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted
$mail->Port = 587; 
$mail->SetFrom('office@barcamp-zukunftsdialog.at');
$mail->From = 'office@barcamp-zukunftsdialog.at';
$mail->FromName = 'BarCamp Zukunftsdialog';
$mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);                     // Add a recipient

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                   // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';                               // Set email format to HTML                             

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'Here is the body';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else {
    echo "<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>Sie haben sich erfolgreich angemeldet!</div>";  
}

mail($_POST['email'], $mail->Subject, $mail->Body);
                        }
else {
     echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>Bitte füllen Sie alle Felder aus, welche mit * markiert sind!</div>";       
}
```

I hope somebody can find the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do `$mail->send()` and then `mail(...)`. Looks to me like one or the other is redundant.

Comment: Also there is a dangling `else` block at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete this line:

```
mail($_POST['email'], $mail->Subject, $mail->Body);
```

The email is already being sent by the following check:

```
if(!$mail->send()) {
```